# Creating MySQL search query from POST array with joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm building a search function for a venue website with some optional search criteria. I'm starting with a basic query and then modifying it based on the parameters submitted.

Here's an example of my db structure:

**venues**

```
id | title
----------
1  | First venue
2  | Second venue
```

**types**

```
id | type
---------
1  | Barn
2  | Hotel
3  | Castle
```

**venues_types**

```
venue_id | type_id
------------------
1        | 1
1        | 2
1        | 3
```

The starting MySQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM venues 
WHERE visible = 1 
$query 
ORDER BY title ASC
```

Here's an example of how I modify the $query variable for a simple option:

```
if(isset($_POST['region']))
    {
      $query .= " AND region_id = " . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['region']);
    }
```

Now, where I'm getting stuck is how to handle when the 'type' option is submitted, which contains multiple values:

```
<select multiple name="type[]">
```

I started trying to create another modifier query but am really struggling to know how to approach this part, how to take the POST array and join the relevant tables.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea how it could be implemented

```
<?php
$sql = [
    "SELECT * FROM `venues` AS `v`",
    "INNER JOIN `venues_types` AS `vt` ON vt.venues_id=v.type_id",
    "INNER JOIN `types` AS `t` ON vt.type_id=t.id",
];

$where = ["v.visible=1"];

if (isset($_POST['region'])) {
    $where[] = "region_id = " . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['region']);
}

if (!empty($_POST['type']) && is_array($_POST['type'])) {
    $where[] = "type_id IN (" .
        implode(
            ",",
            array_map(
                function ($itm) {
                    return (int)$itm;
                },
                $_POST['type']
            )
        ) . ")";
}
$sql[] = "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where);
$sql[] = "ORDER BY v.title ASC";

$sqlAsTxt = implode(" ", $sql);
echo $sqlAsTxt;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! 2 questions, I have some more criteria to add into the query - will that just be a case of adding more to the $where[] array? and finally, is the $sqlAsTxt variable the one I would use as my final query to execute?

Comment: **Q1:** Yes, but fields into where-expression have to being belonged to that three tables or you have to add required tables into sql-statement(e.g. using JOIN).

**Q2:** Yes.

Comment: Thanks Eduard. This is looking good, however the JOIN is outputting the same venue record 3 times if there are 3 results in the venue_types table. Any ideas so I can output unique venues?

Comment: To eliminate this issue try using [DISTINCT](https://w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) statement: ```SELECT DISTINCT v.* FROM venues AS v ...``` Or you may using [GROUP BY](https://w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement: ```... GROUP BY v.id ORDER BY v.title ASC```

Comment: Fiddled and ended up using LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY. Thanks for your help!